# creating 2 model attributes of same object and parsing them to controller with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Im trying to create 2 instances of an object and then parse them to the controller via an `input type="submit"`.

Here's what I have:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/webdata")
public String vorsorgestammdaten(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("Data", new DataOp());
    model.addAttribute("Data2", new DataOp());
    return "/webdata";
}

// Here I want to parse both objects

@RequestMapping(value = "/formdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formdata(HttpServletRequest req, @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser, 
                       DataOp Data, DataOp Data2, Model model) {

    // Do stuff for example
    Data.getName();
    Data2.getName();
}
```

Here is part of my forms:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/formdata}" th:object="${regData}">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input th:field="${Data2.gender}" type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled" /><span>Mr</span>
    <input th:field="${Data2.gender}" type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled"/><span>Frau</span>
    <p>Firstname:</p>
    <input required="required" type="text"  th:field="${Data2.firstname}" placeholder="Max" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input th:field="*{Data.gender}" type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled" /><span>Mr</span>
    <input th:field="*{Data.gender}" type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled"/><span>Frau</span>
    <p>Firstname:</p>
    <input required="required" type="text"  th:field="*{Data.firstname}" placeholder="Max" disabled="disabled" />
    <button type="submit">Speichern</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this `th:object="${regData}"`.

Then you can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

For example,

```
public String formdata(HttpServletRequest req,@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser, @ModelAttribute DataOp Data,@ModelAttribute DataOp Data2, Model model) {
 //Some code
}
```

You might as well switch `*{Data.gender}` to `${Data.gender}`.

Answer (score 0):

add RequestAttribute annotation to each of those params, adding the "name" attribute to differentiate them.

[here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestAttribute.html) you have some info.